# Redirecting after completion of form action

Tags: php, forms, post, redirect, http-headers

i am using the following code for form action,

```
// includes




require_once('inc/mysql_wrapper.php');
$DB=get_db_connection(); 
require_once('inc/defines.inc.php');
require_once('lib/functions.php');
require_once('lib/framework.php');
require_once('lib/specific.php');
require_once('lib/table_editor.php');
require_once('lib/user.php');
require_once('models/basic.php');
require_once('models/list.php');
require_once('swiftmailer/lib/swift_required.php');
require_once('recaptcha/recaptchalib.php');
// end includes

$q="SELECT value FROM $T_SETTINGS
WHERE name='register'";
$register=$DB->oq($q);

$optin=get_setting("optin");

// select custom fields if any
$q="SELECT * FROM $T_FIELDS 
WHERE list_id='$_GET[list_id]'
ORDER BY id";
$efields=$DB->aq($q);

// select mailing list
$q="SELECT * FROM $T_LISTS WHERE id='$_GET[list_id]'";
$list=$DB->sq($q);

if(!empty($_POST['ok']))
{
    // validate recaptcha if required
    if($list['require_recaptcha'])
    {
        $resp = recaptcha_check_answer (RECAPTCHA_PRIVATE,
                                $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_challenge_field"],
                                $_POST["recaptcha_response_field"]);

        if (!$resp->is_valid) 
        {
            $recaptcha_error="Looks like the words you entered are not correct!";        
            $template="templates/register.html";
            require_once('templates/master.html');
            exit;
        }                        
    }

    User::register($_POST, $efields, $optin);

    if(!empty($list['redirect_to']))
    {
        redirect($list['redirect_to']);
        exit;
    }

    $template="templates/message.html";
}
else
{
    $template="templates/register.html";
}

require_once('templates/master.html');
```

excluding some other options, majorly the form data which this form recieves is

> name , email , ok (a flag to check that the the orginating form was submitted)

how can I redirect this page to thanks.php when the form has been submitted?

Comment: At what page are you posting the form?

Comment: the name of the page whose code is posted here is abc.php , and data comes from form.php , the action url is written as *../abc.php?value=15*,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you post it directly in thanks.php?

Thanks.php should control data format and display message, or redirect (by place into header that string: `header('Location: urlOfForm-postedPage);`.

So, if data are correct (and if a control is needed, but I suppose yes) you don't need a redirect.

More over, if controll are done into the original page (simply JS or JQuery?), you can save some redirects.
And that will be more efficient!

Comment: no i can't post it directly to thanks.php, as that is multipurpose page, and i cant add post to it

Comment: @NewBee If is a multipurpose page, just post with your form an hidden element that can identify the referre page. In that way you can add a control onto thanks.php and the trick is done.I don't understand why you can't. If you want to post it directly, so, post your form to referrere page itself (so abc.php). Control (as first operation onto header) if you have posted something and then redirect to thanks.php (but in that way you MUST do a redirect. In the first way I suggest, you can "discount" a step)

Comment: the reason is that, i use same form to post at 3 actions, i am chaining the actions, form-> 1.php->2.php> and the code above is 3rd page on which form data is being sent plus this page is used as admin page (you might have guessed seeing the code), to accomplish the change, i want to redirect it to thanks.php

Comment: @NewBee : so post it to abc.php page directly or to another intermediate page and control, into header, if there is some data post. If it is, use the redirect string that I and some other users suggests to you

Comment: can we come at chat? space isnot enough to provide you complete code

Comment: if i dont exit it, will the page redirected and the script below will run?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7984/discussion-between-n-e-w-b-e-e-and-doncallisto)

Answer (score 2):

When the data is valid, add:

```
header('Location: http://www.example.com/thanks.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything goes well you can use php `header` to get to the desired page:

```
header( 'Location: thanks.php' );
```

Comment: first thing, where should i place it? 2ndly, i did it at the end, but came the error that *header already sent...*

Answer (score 0):

or javascript:

```
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "your>"
</script>

<?php
```